# Drupal 6 Forms formatting

Tags: php, forms, drupal-6, coding-style, drupal-fapi

I am trying to create a form in drupal 6 that has multiple items on the same line. More specificly, I want a right alligned form what has a textfield, dropdown-box, and button all on the same line.

I know how to create the items, but drupal tends to put them all on seperate lines. How do I put it on one line?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to use CSS to position them. Each of them should be in their own div, so it shouldn't be too hard.

P.S. Hard-coding something to be on the same line in your markup is not a good idea. You should always do layout and positioning in your CSS and leave the markup just for outputting items to the page.

Answer (score 1):

Of course I agree with the previous answer: **CSS is the way to go!**. The real question is though: **where should you put the CSS bits?**

I would strongly suggest to put it in a separate .css file, as this will ease a lot the life for other people involved in the project, and keeps the code portable to another theme, when/if the time for a restyling will come. It is pretty easy to do as each from element is generated with its own wrapping *div*. The function you need to use to tell drupal to use a given .css file (if you don't add your styles to an existing one) is [drupal_add_css()](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/drupal_add_js/6).

That said, if you still want/need/must tweak the behaviour you mentioned from the code generating the form, I would suggest you use the [#prefix](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/6#prefix) and [#suffix](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/6#suffix) properties of the `$form` array. These are common to all the form elements and allow you to inject HTML directly into the rendered form (prefix before a given element, suffix after it, of course). This way you could put in the place you need both html elements such `<div>`'s and `<span>`'s and CSS via the `<style type="text/css">` tag.

I want to emphasize though, that the first solution (external CSS file) is way better.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

While I agree that often CSS is the right way to theme the form, sometimes you need stronger methods. I wrote an article about [theming complex forms with tabular information](http://1013.fi/cms/theming-drupal-web-forms), like a list of people with fields for their names and SSNs all printed on one line.

Answer (score 0):

The Drupal Forms API usually outputs each element using a wrapper div element, set with the class name 'form-item'.

eg.

```
<div class="form-item">

  <label> ... </label>
  <input> ... </input>
  <div class="description"> ...</div>

</div>
```

To get three elements to sit next to each other, you'll need to set the width (so that the element are narrow enough to fit on one line), and apply a 'float: left;' using div.form-item as your CSS selector.

To ensure that the elements clear properly, apply 'overflow: hidden;' to the parent element which contains the three form elements.